# How to run netbeans-8.2-linux.sh in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, netbeans-8, ubuntu-18.04

it's been exactly three days that I'm downloading all sorts of versions of netbeans, but in the end I can not run the command ./netbeans-8.2-linux.sh which always shows me an error .

here is somehow the message that sends me the terminal when I execute this command:

```
Configuring the installer...
Searching for JVM on the system...
Extracting installation data...
Running the installer wizard...
No protocol specified

Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
```

So I ask myself the question: how to solve this type of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're missing the `JDK`. most easy might be to install [JDK 8u111 with NetBeans 8.2](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-netbeans-jsp-3413139-esa.html).

this would install both of them. otherwise just install the `JDK` - and then `NetBeans`.